# how to get php errors to show on syslog

Tags: php, error-handling, syslog

I have a script which is scheduled to run on `crontab`. I noticed that I could not see php errors anywhere. I wanted to be able to see php errors logged on `/var/log/syslog` or some place else. I have tried configuring my `php.ini` to log the errors on `/var/log/php-errors.log`, checked permissions and restarted the apache service still no logs.

Comment: What did you put into the php.ini? `error_log` and `log_errors` and `error_reporting` are the Big 3 for logging to file.

Comment: error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log, log_errors = On and error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED

Comment: Does the account it's running under have write permissions in /var/log and on that php-errors.log in particular?

Comment: Im not familiar on how to check if the user has write permissions in /var/log but it does have permissions for php-errors.log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues to consider:

First, PHP CLI uses a different php.ini than the version of PHP that runs via Apache. Make sure you are editing the `error_log` in the CLI version.

Second, make sure your log file is writable by the user that runs cron. Usually the logfile is not writable by your user account, so you may need to edit permissions.

Comment: When logging to syslog you don't write files. The syslog daemon does. This answer doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 10):

I have this in my `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` file (I use Debian; I'm assuming its the same for whatever you are using) and it writes out all cron errors to /var/log/messages:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 0
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
error_log = syslog
```

Answer (score 6):

Try `error_log = syslog` in your php.ini.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 16.04, the /dev/log is owned by group mysyslog (as defined by systemd). So for apache2/php to be able to write into syslog, you must add user www-data to group mysyslog:
`addgroup www-data mysyslog`