# Using syslog facilities with php error_log

Tags: php, syslog

Is posible use syslog **facilities** in php error_log directive or in other way at system/server side?

Something like...

```
error_log = syslog:local4
error_log = syslog(LOG_LOCAL4)
```

Using [php fpm](http://php-fpm.org/) I can set this with syslog.facility directive in fpm conf, but what about of php cli?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469405/how-to-get-php-errors-to-show-on-syslog

Comment: TheClair, I know how send errors to syslog, I want know how if is posible choose facility (local4 for example). I edit the question to explain this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Php default syslog's facility is "user" (and cannot be changed)

I use directive **auto_prepend_file** in phi.ini (this script must be under include_path)

```
auto_prepend_file = log.php
```

and

```
root@sp:/etc/php5/cli# cat /usr/share/php5/log.php
<?php

openlog('php-cli', 0, LOG_LOCAL4);
```

Comment: The facility setting from openlog() seems to persist even after closelog(), so if one does not care about the tag/ident, closelog() may be called just after openlog(). Not sure if that matters as LOG_ODELAY is default. I just noticed a report on http://php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php about a problem with apache-syslog messages being given the same tag as php-messages in the same thread when leaving syslog open.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure error_log content to go to syslog by configuring it in either the CLI or Apache php.ini file; or on a per site basis in your Apache configuration files.

*Warning*, the following will likely cause your 'error_log' messages to be logged to '/var/log/syslog'.
To prevent this, edit '/etc/rsyslog.d/50-defaults.conf', and change:

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
```

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none;local6.none      -/var/log/syslog
```

You may then log your error_log messages to another file by adding a new rule such as:

```
local6.*                          /var/log/local6.log
```

or

```
:syslogtag, isequal, "YOUR_IDENTIFIER:" /var/log/YOUR_IDENTIFIER.log
```

### PHP site wide

For example, to configure all websites to log to syslog, edit the following file:

/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini

Search for, then edit the following values that will be commented out by default:

```
error_log       = syslog
syslog.ident    = YOUR_IDENTIFIER
syslog.facility = local6
```

The above will cause error_log() calls to be logged to "YOUR_IDENTIFIER.log".

Alternatively, for PHP command line programs you can edit:

/etc/php/7.4/php/php.ini

### Apache website specific logging

However, when using Apache, you probably want to log to separate files.
In that case, you only need to update your site specific Apache config file.

Add an appropriate Directory section, and then use the 'php_value' and 'php_admin_value' directives to set these values.
For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
   <Directory /path/to/website/>
   php_value       error_log       syslog
   php_admin_value syslog.ident    YOUR_IDENTIFIER
   php_admin_value syslog.facility local6
   </Directory>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Alternatively, you can use the 'PHPINIDir' directive to make the website use a completely different 'php.ini' file.
For example:

```
<VirtualHost *.80>
...
   PHPINIDir /etc/apache/my_website
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Where the 'my_website' directory contains a copy of 'php.ini' that has been appropriately edited.

### References

1. [Log Files - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html)
2. [How to change configuration settings (PHP Manual)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)
3. [List of php.ini directives (PHP Manaul)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php)
4. [How to specify a customer php.ini for a website](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-specify-a-custom-php.ini-for-a-website-apache2-with-mod_php/)