# Sending errors to syslog in php-fpm

Tags: php, syslog

I'm trying to setup an php-fpm daemon to send error_log to syslog.

My config php-fpm.conf looks thereby.

```
error_log = syslog
syslog.facility = local4
syslog.ident = php-fpm
```

Restarting php-fpm daemon I can see in the remote syslog server.

```
Mar 22 00:32:08 192.168.33.14 php-fpm[20919]: [NOTICE] configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
```

Good!

But when I test this with a real php script with errors, message change to..

```
Mar 22 00:05:59 192.168.33.14 ool www[20889]: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''api'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /var/api/public/index.php on line 2
```

***ool www*** is pool + default pool name (www). So two questions:

- Why I see ***ool www*** instead of ***php-fpm*** (syslog.ident value)?
- Why is pool title is truncated?

Comment: Although my own trick (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569001/using-syslog-facilities-with-php-error-log) fixed the issue, no solves the question.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its a PHP bug :( 
See please

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67764

Answer (score 2):

This issue will become more prevalent as we start to upgrade older systems to php 5.5+, so posting for future reference.

Here is the fix we used, put it as low level as you can so all your scripts can benefit:

```
// This was needed for upgrade to php5.5+ with php-fpm
//  Source: https://gist.github.com/gjuric/e0c9e45efb3d15e3b949
//  Bug History: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575152/sending-errors-to-syslog-in-php-fpm
openlog('php', LOG_ODELAY, LOG_USER);
```