# Is there a way to direct logging to file instead to stdout?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How could I redirect any logging to files to stdout/err/.. ? (to be specific I have rsyslog going)

Basically, I would like what `WC_Log_Handler_File` produces to be redirected, or even piped to stdout/etc. Is there such a way? (preferably through a filter that I have yet to come across)

Comment: You can instruct PHP to [send error logs to syslog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6469461/231316) which might get you something to start with. That, however, is going to interrupt things that expect to be able to read from the file. Another option is to define a [custom steam wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php), maybe.

Comment: Will check the links out - cheers! 

What I got started with so far was defining (overriding the default) `WC_LOG_DIR`, then started to work on a script that would (periodically) check the directory if any new files pop up, and if so, writing the contents of the files inside that directory out. Not sure if it'll end up working out in the end though unless I try!